# Objective-c access struct variable from an array of structs

Tags: objective-c, struct

I have a struct called Point

```
typedef struct {
GLfloat x;
GLfloat y;
} Point;
```

create an array of Points:

```
Point *sPoints;
for(int i=0 ... // define sPoints
```

somewhere else, I want to alter variables on those points. Why does this work:

```
sPoints[100].x+=10;
```

but this doesn't:

```
Point pt = sPoints[100];
pt.x +=10;
```

is there any way to create a temporary variable that refers to the Point structure and allows me to set properties of that struct?  The really strange thing is that in my non working code (pt.x +=10) I can actually read pt.x fine,  I just can't seem to assign it... any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because in C, that operation:

```
Point pt = sPoints[100];
```

creates a copy of the item on the right hand side, whereas the former does not copy.

Comment: but it's the ASSIGNMENT operator! ugh. suppose I should then be using a pointer in this situation...